# Markdown/Text formatting issue in OpenProject/CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, openproject

How can I achieve the following in the issue description field of `OpenProject`?

1. This is the first item
2. This is the second item

   ```
   Line 1
   Line 2
   ```
3. This is the third and last item

A soon as the Rich Text Edior is involved (CKEditor), things are not working as expected.